# Apache basic authentication: Skip authentication for specific patterns only if authenticated earlier

Tags: apache

I have written an angular app that works with a 3rd party backend server that uses Apache to serve pages. Many of my users enable basic authentication in Apache. One of the functions of the server is to send MJPEG image streams that are rendered on browsers using `<img src>` tags. Browsers don't allow `Authorization` headers to be inserted in image tags (and I know there are client side [plugins](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/angular-img-http-src) that try and do this, but so as not to digress, they don't work for MJPEG image streams, so lets assume this is not up for discussion to keep things simple :) ).

So here is what I need to do in my apache config:

1. Enable basic auth for my primary portal, which is `/zm`
2. Disable basic auth for URLs that have `/zm?view=image&<whatever>`
3. Disable basic auth for URLs that have `/zm/cgi-bin/nph-zms?<whatever>`

Now, **in addition**, ideally I'd like to ensure that 2 & 3 rules don't result in a user directly loading those URLs and bypassing security. I'd somehow like to mandate that if the user did not get authenticated in 1, 2&3 won't work either. In other words, I am looking for a means to check if a user has been authenticated in the `/zm` url.

I hope that explains the context

(I am using apache 2.4)

So far I have

```
<Location /zm>
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "/zm/cgi-bin" noauth=1
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "/zm/index.php?view=image" noauth=1 #darn, query params not allowed
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Auth required"
   AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/.htpasswd"
   Require valid-user
   Order Deny,Allow
   Satisfy any
   Deny from all
   Allow from env=noauth
</Location>
```

I have 2 problems:

- The settings above allow a user to navigate to "/zm/cgi-bin" even if
  / is not authenticated (not what I want)
- SetEnvIf doesn't allow query parameters. I need the "view=image" part
  setting no_auth to /index.php is too broad

Thanks

Sidenote: Just to make sure I present the full picture, my `conf-enabled` directory has the following aliases (created by the 3rd party server)

```
ScriptAlias /zm/cgi-bin "/usr/lib/zoneminder/cgi-bin"
<Directory "/usr/lib/zoneminder/cgi-bin">
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /zm /usr/share/zoneminder/www
<Directory /usr/share/zoneminder/www>
  Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
  <IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: What is the apache version?

Comment: hi, I updated the q: 2.4

Comment: But what do you mean by " if 1 is authenticated, skip auth for something"? The credentials will be required only once anyway.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is 2 & 3 should not be allowed if the use did not enter credentials and attempted to access those urls directly

Comment: Do you require authentication for URIs other than 2, 3  and (exactly) `/`? (for example for /foo.html)

Comment: Hi, I've added more context to the Q.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible within apache configuration.